# Link repository files inside a table in a redmine project with multiple repositories

Tags: redmine, textile

I would like to link a repository file in a redmine project with multiple repositories. So I have something like

```
source:svn1|/path/to/file
```

But I want that inside of a table and so I need to escape the `|` because it is interpreted as column separator.

```
|_. File|_.Description|
|source:svn1|/path/to/file|awesome|
```

I am facing the same problem when trying to link a revision inside a table.

```
|_. Revison|_.Description|
|svn1|r758|Bug|
```

Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is using `<notextile>|</notextile>` to escape the `|` in the repository link. So

```
|_.File|_.Description| 
|source:svn1<notextile>|</notextile>/path/to/file|awesome|
```

does the job. The same works for a link to a revision inside a table

```
|_.Revison|_.Description|
|svn1<notextile>|</notextile>r758|Bug|
```